# Is it possible to query cpu utilization of a compute instance using the gcloud api?

Tags: google-compute-engine

When load testing a single core compute instance I noticed top showing only 10% cpu utilization. However, in the compute console the utilization of the instance was 100%. I believe top is showing the utilization of that host while the compute console is showing container utilization. Since the container is more relevant to my load testing I was wondering if it is possible to query this metric via an api command?

```
$ gcloud compute cpu-utilization "instance-name".
```

Something of that sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable Google Cloud Monitoring API for your project and than query the API CPU metric for your instance(s).

You can find more information on Cloud Monitoring API on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/#metrics). I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a dashboard view rather than an API to work with, you might want to try Google Cloud Monitoring with the included agent.  Have you looked at this yet?

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/install-agent